# Find the number overlap between two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one called `gs` and the other called `mmpc`. Each data frame has two columns, but a different number of rows. I am looking to find the **number** of rows that both data frames have in common. Does anyone know how to do this?

Note: the rows are not be in the same order between the two data frames, and the data frames have different numbers of rows.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `merge`:

```
nrow(merge(gs,mmpc,by.x=1:2,by.y=1:2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
sum(duplicated(rbind(gs, mmpc))[-seq_len(nrow(gs))])
```